# While loop executes twice in a row

Tags: c++

I have a while loop with a cin.get() prompt.

```
    char ch;
while (true)
{
    cout<<"Please type in a character:"<<endl;
    cin.get(ch);
    cout<<"ch = "<<ch<<endl; }
```

Once the character is entered and "enter" pressed, the loop executes twice.
Here is the output:

```
Please type in a character:
A
ch = A
Please type in a character:
ch = 

Please type in a character:
```

How do I get rid of that?

Thanks

Comment: @blackbrandt "*`cin.get()` reads up to, but not including, the `\n` at the end of the line*" - that is incorrect. The `istream::get()` and `istream::get(char&)` overloads extract and return a `\n`. You are thinking of the `istream::get(char*, streamsize)` overload instead, which reads but does not extract the `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

On the 1st iteration, `get()` will return the user's character, but the <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`\n`) will still be in the input buffer.  On the 2nd iteration, `get()` will then return that `\n`. And then, on the 3rd iteration, `get()` will block waiting for the user to enter a new character.

You need to discard that `\n` from the input buffer, eg:

```
char ch;
do
{
    cout << "Please type in a character:" << endl;
    cin.get(ch);
    cout << "ch = " << ch << endl;
    if ((ch != '\n') && (cin.peek() == '\n'))
        cin.ignore();
}
while (true);
```

Or, simply use `operator>>` instead, which skips leading whitespace, including `\n`, eg:

```
char ch;
do
{
    cout << "Please type in a character:" << endl;
    cin >> ch;
    cout << "ch = " << ch << endl;
}
while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
cin.ignore()
```

after

```
cin.get()
```

Comment: Note: this will only discard a single letter, so an input of "apples" will effectively print "a", "p", "e" then new line.